# Jquery autocomplete criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

i'm trying to make an autocomplete field in my project.

It works fine, but the autocomplete plugin is too strict for me. Concretely i want the user does **not need to insert the accents to search** by name. So i'm looking for a way to tell the plugin (an option) how to search in the source array.

It'd be helpful too if you can tell me a way to modify the search operation instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accent folding example should accomplish what you are trying to do:

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#folding

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jQuery autocomplete plugin (or any other), you can create entries for the substituted values.

For example, instead of just passing an array of the words with the accent marks present, do a find-and-replace on that array and replace those accented characters with their un-accented equivalents.

Then the autocomplete should respond accordingly

Comment: maybe i have not expressed well enough, but i need that when the user inserts "analisis" the autocomplete plugin matches with "análisis"